# number of requests supported per second by watson assistance, dialog flow and amazon lex

Tags: amazon-lex, watson-assistant, dialogflow-cx

I have been consulting and I have not been able to find out how many requests per second each one can receive without affecting its operation since in the different web pages of these services they give me data per month.

thanks to whoever can help me....

Comment: it depends - on the service plan, on security settings like rate limiting, and the type of requests

Comment: the watson plan is plus

Answer (score 0):

Here are the details pertaining to AWS Lex's limitations.

> When using the PostContent or PostText operations in text mode, the **maximum number of concurrent conversations with a bot is 2 for the $LATEST alias and 50 for all other aliases.** The quota applies separately for each API.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/gl-limits.html#gl-limits-runtime

The processing time would depend on whether you have Lambda functions attached to your Lex bot and how long they take to execute.